# Как удалить и разорвать соединение в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, requests, express

Всем доброго времени суток !) У меня возник вопрос о том как удалить и разорвать соединение.
Допустим у нас генерируются GET запросы:

http://localhost:1337/1

http://localhost:1337/2

http://localhost:1337/3

http://localhost:1337/4

Как разорвать и удалить не все сразу запросы, а только один определенный? Чтобы при переходе на эту страницу оно отображало, что такой страницы нет.
(типа так Cannot GET /localhost:1337/4)

Comment: `res.status(404).send('Not found');`

Comment: А как после изменения статуса на 404 удалить вообще это соединение ? Чтобы его не было. И чтобы потом через `server.getConnections()` мы смогли увидеть, что соединений 3 , а не 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` пойдёт?

```
const http = require('http')

http.createServer((req, resp) => {
  if (req.url === "/1") {
    resp.socket.end(() => console.log("End", req.url))
  } else {
    resp.end("It works", () => console.log(req.method, req.url))
  }
}).listen(8081, '0.0.0.0')
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь) Мне он помог разобраться в данном вопросе)

Comment: @vladisaev, если есть решение именно с connection'ом, запости ответом.

Comment: Ну именно с connection'ом у меня к сожалению нет ответа (